# Error using ng-model in angular directive when doing unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

Let me be a little bit more specific. The code in production works very well (no errors or exceptions in the console). However when I try to do the testing, it doesn't work very well.

This is the relevant bit of my directive template:

```
<form ng-if="totalOrganizations > numOrganizationsForSearch" class="search">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." ng-model="searchText"/>
        </form>
```

The relevant bit of my angular directive:

```
module.exports = function portalSwitcher($state, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        template: template,
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.totalOrganizations = 0;
            scope.searchText = "";

       // more code here
```

I am probably missing something with my testing. The tests works well if the condition `ng-if="totalOrganizations > numOrganizationsForSearch"` is not true and therefore it does not add the `input` field in my directive DOM. However, when this condition is true, my tests fails like that:

```
TypeError: document.createElement is not a function
        at Object.hasEvent (dist/d16cd293c8e995aad0be/vendor.js:22558:34)
        at baseInputType (dist/d16cd293c8e995aad0be/vendor.js:26751:17)
        at textInputType (dist/d16cd293c8e995aad0be/vendor.js:26702:4)
        at pre (dist/d16cd293c8e995aad0be/vendor.js:27292:63)
        at invokeLinkFn (dist/d16cd293c8e995aad0be/vendor.js:13719:10)
        at nodeLinkFn (dist/d16cd293c8e995aad0be/vendor.js:13192:12)
        at compositeLinkFn (dist/d16cd293c8e995aad0be/vendor.js:12609:14)
        at nodeLinkFn (dist/d16cd293c8e995aad0be/vendor.js:13208:25)
        at compositeLinkFn (dist/d16cd293c8e995aad0be/vendor.js:12609:14)
        at publicLinkFn (dist/d16cd293c8e995aad0be/vendor.js:12489:31)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2488:25)
        at Suite.<anonymous> (spec/shared/portalSwitcher.spec.js:168:24)
```

It turns out if I remove the `ng-model` attribute from my `input` I don't get this error at all. So I started to look at the angular code and found where the code is failing:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.9/src/ng/sniffer.js#L34

```
function $SnifferProvider() {
          this.$get = ['$window', '$document', function($window, $document) {
            var eventSupport = {},
                android =
                  toInt((/android (\d+)/.exec(lowercase(($window.navigator || {}).userAgent)) || [])[1]),
                boxee = /Boxee/i.test(($window.navigator || {}).userAgent),
                document = $document[0] || {}, //$document[0] is just an empty object here

            //more code...

if (isUndefined(eventSupport[event])) {
                  var divElm = document.createElement('div'); //exception line. document object is empty and therefore doesn't have createElement function
                  eventSupport[event] = 'on' + event in divElm;
                }
```

It seems for any weird reason, the `$document[0]` object is empty. Which seems from reading the code that shouldn't be the case. I assume some of my test setup is wrong (this is my first directive test). The relevant code is here:

```
    beforeEach(module('app.shared', function($provide) {
            $provide.value('Service1', Service1);
            //other dependencies
        }));

   beforeEach(function() {
      //setup that makes the condition above return true
      //and add ng-model to DOM.
   });

   beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) { //it fails at this line
                elm = $compile('<portal-switcher />')($rootScope.$new());
                scope = elm.isolateScope();

                scope.listPortals();
                scope.$digest();
            }));
```

I tried to fix that providing `$document` in my test with the `document` object from my test (which is not an empty object and contains the `createElement` function) but still same error.

I couldn't find any similar error in Duckduckgo or Google.

I am using angular 1.4.9, angular mocks 1.4.9 as well. I don't think the problem is related to the versions though, I wasn't able to find any issues on angular github repo about that.

Any help is appreciated.